# how to solve this GStreamer library java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError issue?

Tags: java, android, gstreamer, live-streaming

i'm trying to use the GStreaming library in my android application, it compile and everything seems to be ok, but when i run the app it gives me the following error :

```
02-28 21:46:41.033  26177-26177/com.sebasdeldihotmail.parkeafit E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.sebasdeldihotmail.parkeafit, PID: 26177
    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load gstreamer_android from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.sebasdeldihotmail.parkeafit-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.sebasdeldihotmail.parkeafit-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib, /system/lib/arm]]]: findLibrary returned null
            at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:358)
            at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:526)
            at com.sebasdeldihotmail.parkeafit.LasVegas.<clinit>(LasVegas.java:170)
            at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1084)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2126)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5102)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:803)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:619)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

does anyone know how to solve this problem? my brain is dry, i really don't know what to do

Thanks very much for reading.

here it is

```
static {
        System.loadLibrary("gstreamer_android");
        System.loadLibrary("rtsp");
        nativeClassInit();
    }
```

and yes, there are 2 .so files 
called libgstreamer_android.so
and librtsp.co

Comment: No native library corresponding to the name you passed to System.loadLibrary() and compatible with the ABI of your device is present in your apk file.  Did you put one where the packager would pick it up?  Open the apk as a zip file and see if there are any .so files inside.  Post their names, and also the argument you pass to loadLibrary()

Comment: In what folders are they found?  What type of device are your running on?

Comment: for some reason i have them in 2 folders

Comment: parkeafit > libs > armeabi > the 2 .so files

Comment: and also in parkeafit > app > src > main > jnilibs > armeabi > the 2 .so files @ChrisStratton

Comment: The strange thing is that i have the folders in the same place that in another project that works perfectly in the same device.

Comment: See if the hello-jni project from the NDK samples will work.  If it does, you may be able to find the error by experimentally merging that with your project and seeing what works/breaks at what level of integration.

Comment: Could you show your Android.mk & Application.mk?

Comment: Just use parkeafit > libs > armeabi > the 2 .so files, remove another.

Comment: the .so had a different library path on the native language, already solve the problem, thanks very much for helping guys.

Comment: @SebastianDelgado So, I'm stuck in the same problem, how did you solve it?!!